# Java + MySQL - Syntax error but the statement is correct

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

My program executes INSERT query. When I run it, I get an error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO words(lang1, lang2, category, lang2_code, user) SELECT 'ahoj', 'hell' at line 1

I tried to print the actual statement to the stdout:

```
SET @lang:='Angličtina', @categ:='Nová';
INSERT INTO words(lang1, lang2, category, lang2_code, user)
SELECT 'ahoj', 'hello', c.id, l.id, 1 FROM categories c, languages l
WHERE c.name = @categ AND l.name = @lang;
```

As you can see, the statement is altered in the log. `'hell'` instead of `'hello'`. When I copy that into the mysql command line and execute, it works just fine so I assume the problem is in the JDBC somewhere.

Comment: can you share your java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not **one** statement. If you want to use more than one statement at a time, don't use a `PreparedStatement` but for example `addBatch` but it seems that here you should simply issue 2 JDBC statements, one after the other.

Comment: what if I need the `preparedStatement`?

Comment: Then use **2** preparedStatement, not one. You can't have a semicolon in the middle of a statement, prepared or not.

Comment: ok if there is no other option, then I assume this is answer I needed, thanks

Comment: @dystroy looks like OP is attempting a nested query. How will 2 statements solve that problem?

Comment: @jlordo There's a nested query, which is fine, but there's also a first SET statement before that.